# can we change an application's connection settings such as data source and initial catalogue using appcmd command

Tags: iis, connection-string, appcmd

I have a .Net web application whose connection string i am trying to change using command line tool appcmd (available in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv).

Is it feasible coz i am not able to do it after trying multiple attempts. 
No direct reference is available for this but i am trying to use below mentioned query in terms of connection string.

appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name=’MyAppPool’].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name=’MyAppPool’].processModel.userName:MyDomain\MyAccount /[name=’MyAppPool’].processModel.password:MyAccountPassword

so my query would become

appcmd set config /section:connectionStrings /[name=’ConnectionStringName’].password:test

but its not working. I am trying to change few more entries in connection string but not able to change even one.

As a work-around, i am deleting the existing connection string and adding a new one with same one and settings i need. But there must be a simpler way to do this.

Can anybody help in resolution?
I will really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after some googling. Below is the required connection string I was looking for

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" /section:connectionStrings /+"[name='TestString', connectionString='Data Source=TestDBServer\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=TestCatalog;User Id=sa;password=test', providerName='System.Data.SqlClient']"
```

Please note the + sign before 'name'. It's assuming that no connection string is available with this name. If it does, remove it first and then perform the above step.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can I get connectionsstrings list using appcmd ?